# Bound on volume of $A-B$ according to Minkowski

Tags: real-analysis, geometry, volume

$A-B:=\{c:B+c\subseteq A\}$, in, say, Euclidean space.

I think that if $A-B$ is not the universe, then $vol(A-B)\leq vol(A)$ (If $B$ has one point then the inequality is immediate, adding more points to $B$ can only reduce $vol(A-B)$ by set theoretic consideration.) Is there anything tighter?

Comment: Your argument is correct. Also, equality holds when $B$ is a singleton. What do you mean by 'tighter'?

Comment: Beware that you use a standard notation in a non-standard way. The conventional definition (which, I believe, originates from Minkowski's work) is $A-B=\{a-b\colon a\in A,\ b\in B\}$.

Comment: Alright thanks for the information. I am taking mine from the wiki definition.